# How to schedule a job using JobScheduler only when device is not in doze (not even Maintenance window)?

Tags: android

The JobInfo.Builder has a method for setting device idle state but i am confused as to what it is exactly trying to say.

```
setRequiresDeviceIdle (boolean requiresDeviceIdle)

Specify that to run, the job needs the device to be in idle mode. This defaults to false.

Idle mode is a loose definition provided by the system, which means that the device is not in use,
and has not been in use for some time. As such, it is a good time to perform resource heavy jobs.
Bear in mind that battery usage will still be attributed to your application, and surfaced to the user in battery stats.
```

Now the description for the boolean is as follows:

```
requiresDeviceIdle  boolean: Whether or not the device need be within an idle maintenance window.
```

I basically need the job to fire when the device is not dozing, preferably not even in the maintenance window. The purpose of the job is to download stuff from a network.

Will setting it false cause it to run when the device is not in the maintenance window? ( the actual deep sleep state IDLE and the running state)

will setting it to true cause it to run only in the maintenance windows and in no other cases?

Comment: `setRequiresDeviceIdle()` is not the doze mode idle state. It just means the screen is off. check the official doc.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder?utm_campaign=adp_series_job_scheduler_092216&utm_source=medium&utm_medium=blog#setRequiresDeviceIdle%28boolean%29

Answer (score 2):

Setting `setRequiresDeviceIdle(true)` will run the scheduled job in the maintenance window of device dozing.

A Maintenance window is a period of dozing(idle state) where all accumulated jobs are given a chance to run for a specific period of time and then the device goes to doze again and then after some time the maintenance window time started and the cycle will be repeated. So when you set `true` to `setRequiresDeviceIdle()` you job will be executed only in those maintenance windows.

[image]

So if you want your job to run at any time(even when the user is using the device) then set `setRequiresDeviceIdle()` to `false`

Comment: I want it to be used especially when the device is active... And only when it is active.

Comment: But what is the problem with the job running in the maintenance window too?

Comment: Problem is if i set the damned flag true, it'll only run in maintenance window and if to false only in the active state... Thats why no mw. Suggest something if you have an alternative

Comment: if set to false only in the active state -- i think that is not correct. if set to false it will it run whenever possible. means either active or idle it will run

Comment: Hmm so i guess keeping a network required flag and the idle flag to false should ensure it working only when there is internet and the device isnt necessarily idle ie whenever possible.

Comment: `setRequiresDeviceIdle()` is not the doze mode idle state. It just means the screen is off. check the official doc.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder?utm_campaign=adp_series_job_scheduler_092216&utm_source=medium&utm_medium=blog#setRequiresDeviceIdle%28boolean%29