# Can JobScheduler in Doze mode can connect network?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

As Google document mentioned, JobScheduler can not work in Doze mode, Unless it is in temporal windowed periodic wake-up time.

reference
https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby?hl=en

But some people said it can work even in Doze mode...
in the following link.
[How to schedule a job using JobScheduler only when device is not in doze (not even Maintenance window)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440667/how-to-schedule-a-job-using-jobscheduler-only-when-device-is-not-in-doze-not-ev?rq=1)

Which one is true?
if it can work in Job Scheduler in doze mode, can it use the network(Wifi and mobile network) in doze mode?

And jobscheduler in doze mode, will wake system? or just the app?

Comment: Just set a network constraint on the job and let the OS figure out when to run it

Comment: There are only a few whitelisted apps running whilst in Doze mode. So your best bet would be to make use of those. For instance, implement Firebase and use push notifications to wake the device in case a of a messaging app. If you are doing checks to see whether data updated or not on a server, rather push a notifcation to your app (Which will wake it up), consume the notification and update your data

Comment: Just want to add, I've tried JobScheduler but got a ton of "App is Draining Battery" messages after a few hours of the app just sitting in the background. I implemented push notifications to wake the device only when needed, those messages are gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JobScheduler will work with the network if you add `setRequiredNetworkType` irrespective of doze mode or not. Though while in doze mode it will run during the maintenance window & the OS will decide the right time.

Other than that to clarify `setRequiresDeviceIdle()` is not the doze mode idle state but just another screen off state but not necessarily with doze mode active.

[Check the "charging & idle" section in this article by google devs](https://medium.com/google-developers/scheduling-jobs-like-a-pro-with-jobscheduler-286ef8510129)

[Official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder?utm_campaign=adp_series_job_scheduler_092216&utm_source=medium&utm_medium=blog#setRequiresDeviceIdle%28boolean%29)

> Despite the similar naming, this job constraint is not related to the system's "device idle" or "doze" states. This constraint only determines whether a job is allowed to run while the device is directly in use.